# Postgres Function return the category name that equals the category id

Tags: postgresql

I am having trouble running my function, it is supposed to return the categ name as the name for the category where the categ id equals the category id from the category table. The ERROR Im getting is ERROR: syntax error at or near "END" LINE 8: END;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custTrans(categ_id int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(45) AS $$
DECLARE categ_name varchar(45)
 BEGIN
  SELECT c.name INTO categ_name
  FROM category AS c
  WHERE c.category_id = categ_id
 END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

My current code is a rework of the original and I have try making it into an if statement, but it didnt work.

Comment: a) you're missing a semicolon b) no reason for pl/pgsql here, use a plain sql function

Comment: Thank you, Im new to posting and didnt know how to format the code in the question.

Comment: You need to `RETURN categ_name;` just before the `END;` hence the error *ERROR: syntax error at or near "END" LINE 8: END;*.  See docs [Return](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I don't think the syntax error is complaining about the missing `RETURN` statement, rather it's complaining about the missing `;` to terminate the `SELECT` statement

Comment: @Bergi, I missed that.